# Random load balancing in Apache

Tags: apache, load-balancing, mod-proxy-balancer

I'm trying to setup some load balancing for my server.
Using mod_proxy_balancer everything seems pretty straightforward.
my problem is that I need a **random** balancing algorithm (as to why i would want that, its a client's request).

As far as i can see the available options for **lbmethod** are **byrequests bytraffic byrequests**
is there any way to get random balancing without writing my own module (won't be that difficult, but still i would like to avoid it )

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no random balancing option in mod_proxy_balancer. You can easily patch mod_proxy_balancer to do that.